# Is Octave compatible with the CobraToolbox?

Tags: octave, matlab

I need to use the `CobraToolbox` for a course and I am wondering if it is compatible with Octave.

[Even googling for this](https://www.google.pt/search?q=cobra+toolbox+octave&oq=co&aqs=chrome.1.57j59j60l4.1485&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) doesn't return much results..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone has published their results, you can't know without trying it.  However, there is a very high likelihood that it will work on Octave, here's what [Jordi](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=224167) has to say on this issue answering this [question](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/query-on-using-matlab-toolboxes-in-Octave-td4527064.html).

> I am new to Octave and was wondering if it is possible to use matlab
>   toolboxes in Octave?
>
> It depends on what you mean by "Matlab toolbox". If you mean the code
>   that came with Matlab, it's probably a license violation to use it
>   with Octave, assuming you can compile it for Octave when it's
>   necessary to compile.
>
> If you mean free code out there you found on the internet that was
>   written for Matlab, it is likely it will work on Octave. Just try it.
>   If you need to compile mex files, the "mkoctfile --mex" command may be
>   of use.
>
> If you want to have a rough equivalent of the Matlab toolboxes in
>   Octave, try the Octave-Forge packages:

My personal experience is that Octave has become extremely good at accepting Matlab code.  I would hazard a guess that any time you spend setting up Octave and this toolbox will be worth it.  Even the MEX files appear to have a portability mechanism.  Unless they are using some very specific features like [addpref](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpref.html) for toolbox persistent data, it will slide right into Octave.  Even if they are using the prefs, it could be modified to live in Octave.